# CSS - Create/Use Master Stylesheet

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I read an article online for tips using CSS and one of the pointers was:

> Use a master stylesheet. “One of the most common mistakes I see
>   beginners and intermediates fall victim to when it comes to CSS is not
>   removing the default browser styling. This leads to inconsistencies in
>   the appearance of your design across browsers, and ultimately leaves a
>   lot of designers blaming the browser. It is a misplaced blame, of
>   course. Before you do anything else when coding a website, you should
>   reset the styling.”

Could anyone point me to any tutorials (or even help on here) as to how I can setup a Master CSS Page for my website, and also how I can call classes from the Master CSS Page to objects in my webpages.

For example if I set some styles in my Master CSS page,
I could set class on a div to **class="main-header-blue"** and it would call that style from my Master CSS Page and apply it to my div (and I could call this class from any of my web page)

Any help or advice is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: FWIW, don't dump the default browser styles. A CSS reset is what you are looking for, and they include all sorts of unnecessary cruft (like hiding :focus states). Inconsistencies across browsers is normal and part of a conformant, future-proof web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope my interpretation is your answer:

CSS is applying styles from a top-down perspective. This means, if you insert two stylesheets, the top one is applied first and then the second one overrides the first stylesheet

That means that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle2.css"> // this one overrides the first
```

That applies to styles too:

```
div {
  background-color:green;
}

div {
  background-color:red;
}
// the background color is red.
```

That could mean that the first stylesheet is the master stylesheet. That one is containing the 'master styles' and the second one is for 'overriding the defaults'. This is useful when you import a stylesheet from 3rth parties (e.g. *Bootstrap*).

---

A second interpretation is SASS. Within SASS you can create a master stylesheet containing the variables that will be applied in the other stylesheets. So, in the master stylesheet you say this:

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;
```

Then in your other stylesheets you use those:

```
body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

Comment: While totally true, I think he's refering to css reset (normalize.css/reset.css/etc.)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for! Will accept when available.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is [Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). By including this asset prior to your own custom styles, it will help to remove browser inconsistencies with things like margins and padding on the document.

Otherwise, just style as you would normally and you should just be fine. Let me know if you have any other questions!

Answer (score 0):

The basic way of setting a "master" stylesheet is the following:

Assume you have a folder structure like this:

- webpage (folder)

  - css (folder)

    - style.css (file)
  - index.html (file)

Lets say you have a file called index.html at the root of your project folder. You need to include/reference the stylesheet (style.css) in the index.html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mydiv">Your content</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you can have this in your style.css file:

```
.mydiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

This will make the `<div>`inside the `<body>`to have a `width` and `height` of 300 pixels and a `background-color` of red. And you can call this style anywhere inside the webpage by giving a `<div>` the class `mydiv`.

That is it simply put.